# Teamcity Compilation error: javac Class not found: javac1.8

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, teamcity

As title suggests, I'm having an issue trying to get my build.xml file to generate an apk on Teamcity from Subversion. The build.xml was generated by Ant within Eclipse, but each time I try to commit a change via Subversion, TC decides to poop itself and gives me the error:

Teamcity Compilation error: javac Class not found: javac1.8

I'm not too sure where to go with this; I've spent quite a bit of time researching the error code here, and elsewhere, and I don't seem to get anything solid from it - I have followed installation instructions to the letter for Ant, Eclipse ADT and TC and I've set up (at least I think I have) each software correctly.

I am quite new to the programming scene, so I am hoping someone can help.

Thanks,

Niko

Comment: can you post more output when you got this error?

Comment: Result:  Compilation error: javac Agent: CS-NIKO
Time: 24 Nov 14 15:41:00 - 15:41:06 (5s) Triggered by: you on 24 Nov 14 15:40
Investigation: 
Start investigation of current problems in this build configuration (Android App)
 Build problems
  
Compilation error (1)
 Build failure reason Compilation error: javac
Class not found: javac1.8

Answer (score 0):

For Android development, I stick with Java 1.6 which is the one supported by Android. So it looks like you're using 1.8, can you try to use 1.6 to see if you still have the issue?